# Windows, Python: time.sleep() permission error

Tags: python, windows, permissions, sleep, rights

In my Python Script, I am using the function time.sleep(10) to make the script sleep for 10 seconds. I am correctly importing the time module and the code works perfectly fine when running on MacOS.

Even the most basic approach doesn't work:

```
import datetime
import time

print(datetime.datetime.now())
time.sleep(10)
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

When trying to run it on Windows, however, my Command Prompt displays something like „the client is missing a right“. I‘ve tried multiple things now, like moving the file to another directory (e.g. the Python directory) or trying it on the admin account... Nothing has helped. Also, it doesn't work on any of my other Windows machines either.

How can I solve that problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your code.

Comment: Code added, even the simplest version doesn't work

Comment: did you try to start your program as admin?

Comment: @Lupos oh wow, running it in the PowerShell as Administrator surprisingly worked... Although I ran it from my Admin Account before... strange - do you know why that is? Also, do you know how to run Python Scripts as Admin from a .bat file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it run it as admin.
I am sorry, I don't know why it doesn't work from your admin account.
And to run a `.bat` file as admin you can just righclick the file and run as admin.
[image]